# To show that $\langle\mathbb Q,+\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $\langle\mathbb Q \setminus\{0\} , \,\cdot\,\rangle$

Tags: group-theory

For this question is it enough to say that they both dont have same cardinality so they are not isomorphic.Can we exhibhit any structural property diference here? THANKS

Comment: But they do have the same cardinality.

Comment: 0 is not there in second set

Comment: Hint: Can you find some elements of finite order?

Comment: @SophieClad: That doesn't mean they have different cardinalities. If $X$ is a finite set, then $X$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$ have different cardinalities, but if $X$ is infinite, $X$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$ have the same cardinality.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes i see now thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:

$\mathbb{Q}^\times$ has an element of order $2$.

---

Side note:  $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ actually have the same cardinality.  One defining feature of infinite sets is that an infinite set and a proper subset of it can have equal cardinalities, so we must be careful in that regard.

Comment: Just to nitpick, I believe every infinite set must have at least one proper subset with the same cardinality.

Comment: For isomorphism the no. Of  elements having same order should be present in both groups ? Am i correct?

Comment: Indeed!  Can you prove it?  To get started, if $\phi:G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is an isomorphism, then $\phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n$.

Comment: @KajHansen 1 is of order 2 in Q* , but in Q 0 has order 2

Comment: @SophieClad, careful.  The identity element in a group has order $1$.  There is a non-identity element in $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ with order $2$, but there is not such an element in $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.

Comment: @KajHansen oh yes ! So -1 has order 2 in Q* . But how to confirm that none has order 2 in Q ? Because if i say there is a in Q of order 2 , i write 2a=0 implies a=0 so trivially i get identity which is of order 1 .Am i correct ?

Comment: Yep!  There you go!

Answer (score 0):

Also, note that $\mathbb Q^\times\cong \mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z^{\oplus\mathbb N}$, whereas no to elements of $(\mathbb Q, +)$ are independent.